# Unrecognized OpenGL functions with QOpenGLContext in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I want to make a cross-platform OpenGL Qt Project in QT Creator. I cloned this repository
https://github.com/advancingu/Qt5OpenGL
to my Mac, and was able to build and compile. It rendered a rainbow triangle on a black background.

I tried building on Windows, but got the following compiler errors;

```
undefined reference to '_imp_glGetError@0'
undefined reference to '_imp_glGetString@04'
undefined reference to '_imp_glGetString@04'
undefined reference to '_imp_glGetString@04'
undefined reference to '_imp_glGetString@04'
In function 'ZN15BasicUsageScene6renderEV:
undefined reference to '_imp_glClear@4'
undefined reference to '_imp_glDrawArrays@4'
```

... and so on.
 What do I have to do to build the project? I'm on Windows 8.1 64 Bit. My project is using MinGW_32bit-Debug to make.

Alternatively, if there is a good way to build a cross-platform QT Creator OpenGL project, I'm all ears. I've spent at least a dozen hours trying to import GLEW libraries in my project folder, to no avail (my project with an import GLEW library actually threw the exact same error). But I'm thinking using QT's built in OpenGL functionality would be the best approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, a lot of people (including myself) use [GLLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) for access to OpenGL, instead of GLEW. As you said though, Qt also provides it's own GL bindings you can use, so you shouldn't need either.

How are you are linking to OpenGL? On Windows you have to link to "opengl32". The project file doesn't seem to do that, but perhaps qmake automatically does it if you add Qt Gui.

The only other thing I can think of is that there is an issue with your windows install, like wrongly configured / missing drivers. Especially if, as you say, GLEW gives the same issue. Can you build any program that uses OpenGL on this machine? Using SFML or SDL, for example.